# If I have one lat/lng which I assume is at 0,0 then how do I calculate the x, y coordinates of another lat/lng pair?

Tags: javascript, math, coordinates, geo

I've seen many variations of this question asked but am having trouble relating their answers to my specific need.

I have several sets of 3 lat/lng coordinate pairs. The coordinates in any set are within a few km of eachother.

For each set I would like to convert the coordinates to x/y values so that I can plot them.

I would like to assign 1 of the coordinates to 0,0 and then compute the relative x/y values of the other two coordinates.

This site does what I want but unfortunately doesn't share the algorithm:
http://www.whoi.edu/marine/ndsf/cgi-bin/NDSFutility.cgi?form=0&from=LatLon&to=XY

Comment: of course, since the earth is a sphere, it depends on the strategy used to flatten it up. I don't know what is your problem, but any good API for map plotting would let you plot some points just by their lat/lng values. For example, Google Maps' API does this.

Comment: How accurate do you want to be. You can use what is known as Spherical Mercator (a projection from lat/lon to a planar surface, developed for Google Maps) to convert your coordinates to meters and then it would be a simple matter to normalize so that one of them was at 0,0, and the rest relative to that, by subtracting the same amount from all of them.

Comment: because my points are so close together (< 2500m) i assume that accuracy won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. First some definitions just to be clear

   - let `a` be latitude `<-pi/2,+pi/2>`
   - let `b` be longitude `<0,+2*pi>`
   - let `re`,`rp` be equator and pole radiuses of Earth
   - `a0,b0, a1,b1, a2,b2` are your points in spherical coordinates
   - and `x0,y0, x1,y1, x2,y2` are your wanted cartesian coordinates
2. convert coordinates to relative to (`a0,b0`)

   - Leta assume East is aligned to your X-axis and North pole is aligned to Y-axis
   - `x0=0.0;`
   - `y0=0.0;`
   - `r1=re*cos(a1)+rp*sin(a1)` // actual radius for point 1
   - `r2=re*cos(a2)+rp*sin(a2)` // actual radius for point 2
   - `x1=x0+((b1-b0)*r1);`
   - `x2=x0+((b2-b0)*r2);`
   - `y1=y0+((a1-a0)*re);` // here instead of re should be length of ellipse curve from 0 to a1-a0
   - `y2=y0+((a2-a0)*re);` // here instead of re should be length of ellipse curve from 0 to a2-a0

if re!=rp then the y1,y2 coordinates will be less accurate

- to correct that just replace ((a1-a0)*re) with the propper formula
- for ellipse arc->length computation (this one is for circle)
- I am too lazy to compute that integral
- anyway even this is good enough (earth eccentricity is not that bad)
- you also can normalize the angles after substraction
- `while (a<-pi)` a+=2.0*pi;`
- `while (a>+pi)` a-=2.0*pi;`
- just to be safe ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that's not entirely true. The site *does* share the algorithm, just not in the way one would expect to.

See http://www.whoi.edu/marine/ndsf/utility/NDSFutility.js .

Hope that helps.

Comment: While the link you provided may answer the question, it is best to post the essential parts of your solution directly in your Stack Overflow answer in case the link becomes invalid in the future.